# CakePHP - download text file that uses database info

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller function that fetches data from the database based on user input and stores it in an array, `$results`, which I use to generate a table in the view. Pretty straightforward.

Now I want to put in a button to download the results to a text file (in a more text-file-friendly format). If I make a new page/controller function called `download` and try to generate the text there, I won't have access to my `$results`, and it's ill-advised to pass an array (or a very large string) back to a controller.

What would be the best way of going about this? I'm using CakePHP 2.4.1.

Comment: try this may help you [http://pastebin.com/u46cWX7T](http://pastebin.com/u46cWX7T)

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you re-use your controller code in the new function 'download' to rebuild the $result array? And after that you realise that you should have a model function to build that array so you can indeed re-use it in the controller :)

so in short, make it a model function you can call from anywhere in your controller